# Randomize rows update

Tags: mysql

Sometime I have over 1 millions rows in the table.

Each batch will have 100,000 of randomize rows.

What is the best way to randomize rows?

I do the following:

```
UPDATE  temp1 SET  `batch` =  '';
UPDATE  temp1 SET  `batch` =  'B1' WHERE batch = '' order by rand(number) limit 100000;
UPDATE  temp1 SET  `batch` =  'B2' WHERE batch = '' order by rand(number) limit 100000;
UPDATE  temp1 SET  `batch` =  'B3' WHERE batch = '' order by rand(number) limit 100000;
UPDATE  temp1 SET  `batch` =  'B4' WHERE batch = '' order by rand(number) limit 100000;
UPDATE  temp1 SET  `batch` =  'B5' WHERE batch = '' order by rand(number) limit 100000;
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do randomizing update? (since at the end, all matched rows would be updated)

Comment: I am randomizing `numbers` field because currently numbers are sorted in order. Once it has been randomized, I export each batch to CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to have exactly 100000 records per batch, you could use rand() to build a random batch string, and statistically, each batch should have ~100000 records

```
UPDATE temp1
JOIN   (
    SELECT number, CONCAT('B',CONVERT( FLOOR( RAND() * (nrows/10) ) + 1, CHAR(19) )) AS randBatch
    FROM   temp1
    CROSS JOIN ( SELECT COUNT(*) AS nrows FROM temp1 ) as x
   ) AS y
ON     y.number = temp1.number
SET    batch = randBatch
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eb161/1